# regex match everything between two different characters

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string-matching

I want to match a string between (but not including) these two characters: `?` and `&`

Example string:

```
localhost/path/doc.html?970441179&token=specialtoken&actionurl=/portletaction/01654/0112
```

So from the above I want to match the string `970441179`

Comment: Use a proper URL parser

Comment: @MattBurland it seems pretty specific to get that substring instead of parsing and getting all parameters from url..

Comment: [`\?(.*?)&`](https://regex101.com/r/xLOw7G/1)

Comment: @MattBurland I see no .net or c# tags here, sir.

Comment: or `\?\K.*?(?=&)` if you don't need grouping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = "?samplestring&";
var patt = /[?]([^&]*)[&]/g;
var res = patt.exec(str)[1];
```

'res' is your desired result.

Comment: I'd write `/\?([^&]*)\&/` - or is there an advantage using single-character character-groups? (also no need for global matching)

Comment: You can use any one of them. I don't think there is any advantage of using single-character character-groups and also there is no need for global matching. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex `(\d+)(?=&)`:

```js
var str = "localhost/path/doc.html?970441179&token=specialtoken&actionurl=/portletaction/01654/0112";

console.log(str.match(/(\d+)(?=&)/g));
```

Note that it will work just for that specific case.

Comment: Swap the order of the query string parameters and this will break.

Comment: @MattBurland ***"Note that it will work just for that specific case"***